TLS handshake fails with a subdomain of a let's-encrypt wildcard-domain certificate
I've a Raspberry Pi with a setup including PiHole and caddy.
PiHole serves as local DNS server for the network, and caddy is used as reverse proxy on a generic corresponding service.
Example:

(DNS record set) 192.168.2.71 nextcloud.foo.duckdns.org
(Caddyfile) nextcloud.foo.duckdns.org { reverse_proxy localhost:11000 }

$ curl --head --verbose https://nextcloud.foo.duckdns.org
*   Trying [2a02:a458:814f:0:a438:1aab:a24:12f7]:443...
*   Trying 192.168.2.71:443...
* Connected to nextcloud.foo.duckdns.org (192.168.2.71) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=nextcloud.foo.duckdns.org
*  start date: May  1 05:58:44 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Jul 30 05:58:43 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "nextcloud.foo.duckdns.org" matched cert's "nextcloud.foo.duckdns.org"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.

In the Caddyfile I also have a global option/block, { acme_dns duckdns <my-token> }, and I've also generated a valid certificate with Let's Encrypt using this guide: https://github.com/infinityofspace/certbot_dns_duckdns?tab=readme-ov-file#usage
This certificate includes both "foo.duckdns.org" and "*.foo.duckdns.org" as domains.
Now, however, I set up another service, home-assistant, and I added an entry in the Caddyfile, that is homeassistant.foo.duckdns.org { reverse_proxy localhost:8123 }.
The issue is that the TLS handshake fails, and thus the HTTPS request.
curl --head --verbose https://homeassistant.foo.duckdns.org
*   Trying 192.168.2.71:443...
* Connected to homeassistant.foo.duckdns.org (192.168.2.71) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, internal error (592):
* OpenSSL/3.0.11: error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL/3.0.11: error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error

I'm still able to access the service via the localhost interface, though.
$ curl --verbose 192.168.2.71:8123
*   Trying 192.168.2.71:8123...
* Connected to 192.168.2.71 (192.168.2.71) port 8123 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.2.71:8123
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Server:
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Length: 4116
< Date: Sat, 04 May 2024 15:19:24 GMT
<
< HTML response

Why this difference? I also tried running sudo certbot renew but the tool says Certificate not yet due for renewal
The caddy logs related to this request are:
May 04 17:07:55 raspberrypi caddy[2499813]: {"level":"debug","ts":1714835275.669332,"logger":"http.stdlib","msg":"http: TLS handshake error from 172.24.0.8:52236: EOF"}
May 04 17:07:56 raspberrypi caddy[2499813]: {"level":"error","ts":1714835276.0812566,"logger":"tls.issuance.zerossl.acme_client","msg":"cleaning up solver","identifier":"homeassistant.foo.duckdns.org","challenge_type":"dns-01","error":"no memory of presenting a DNS record for \"_acme-challenge.homeassistant.foo.duckdns.org\" (usually OK if presenting also failed)"}
May 04 17:07:56 raspberrypi caddy[2499813]: {"level":"debug","ts":1714835276.4435985,"logger":"tls.issuance.zerossl.acme_client","msg":"http request","method":"POST","url":"https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90/authz/PyhpCsoS_EhSSiEGi8UeIQ","headers":{"Content-Type":["application/jose+json"],"User-Agent":["Caddy/2.7.6 CertMagic acmez (linux; arm64)"]},"response_headers":{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":["*"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, no-cache, no-store"],"Content-Length":["145"],"Content-Type":["application/json"],"Date":["Sat, 04 May 2024 15:07:56 GMT"],"Link":["<https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90>;rel=\"index\""],"Replay-Nonce":["igkSNJLHTzdfI2aSomwLOusaK7Fz3HQEHXL8NYrFcWA"],"Server":["nginx"],"Strict-Transport-Security":["max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains"]},"status_code":200}
May 04 17:07:56 raspberrypi caddy[2499813]: {"level":"error","ts":1714835276.4437563,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"could not get certificate from issuer","identifier":"homeassistant.foo.duckdns.org","issuer":"acme.zerossl.com-v2-DV90","error":"[homeassistant.foo.duckdns.org] solving challenges: presenting for challenge: could not determine zone for domain \"_acme-challenge.homeassistant.foo.duckdns.org\": unexpected response code 'REFUSED' for _acme-challenge.homeassistant.foo.duckdns.org. (order=https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90/order/uQxNVkgga-pcqKOgZWOJiA) (ca=https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90)"}
May 04 17:07:56 raspberrypi caddy[2499813]: {"level":"debug","ts":1714835276.4437943,"logger":"events","msg":"event","name":"cert_failed","id":"9ff6162d-a94e-497f-aff9-5d068ddc2987","origin":"tls","data":{"error":{},"identifier":"homeassistant.foo.duckdns.org","issuers":["acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org-directory","acme.zerossl.com-v2-DV90"],"renewal":false}}
May 04 17:07:56 raspberrypi caddy[2499813]: {"level":"error","ts":1714835276.4438388,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"will retry","error":"[homeassistant.foo.duckdns.org] Obtain: [homeassistant.foo.duckdns.org] solving challenges: presenting for challenge: could not determine zone for domain \"_acme-challenge.homeassistant.foo.duckdns.org\": unexpected response code 'REFUSED' for _acme-challenge.homeassistant.foo.duckdns.org. (order=https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90/order/uQxNVkgga-pcqKOgZWOJiA) (ca=https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90)","attempt":13,"retrying_in":1800,"elapsed":9168.216986793,"max_duration":2592000}


It looks like the issue lied in using PiHole as DNS server for the entire network (set it as only DNS server in the router settings).
This thread in the caddy forum helped me with an unexpected option in the tls block: resolvers.
Setting this to Google DNS, i.e., 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 was enough to let caddy solves the DNS challenge.

This is unrelated to certificate validation. It is not about the client complaining about the server certificate, but the server complaining about something coming from the client. Because of this the server sends an TLS alert back to the client:
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, internal error (592):
* OpenSSL/3.0.11: error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error


I'm still able to access the service via the localhost interface, though.
$ curl --verbose 192.168.2.71:8123


This is not doing a HTTPS request, but a plain HTTP request. This means no TLS is done and therefore also no TLS related errors will happen.

The caddy logs related to this request are:
... "tls.obtain","msg":"could not get certificate from issuer","identifier":"homeassistant.foo.duckdns.org", ...


This suggests that the internal server was setup to automatically get a certificate for this subdomain (i.e. not setup to use an existing wildcard) but was unable to retrieve the certificate.
This also explains the handshake error: the server fails with the TLS handshake since it has no usable certificate for the requested domain.

I dig a bit into caddy specifics, and it looks like the correct way of working with wildcard certificates is this one: https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https#wildcard-certificates
However, even if I follow the example found here: https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/patterns#wildcard-certificates , I still get the same error related to the challenge. Why this is happening now, and only for a subsets of domains?

@crissal: There are too few information about your specific setup, what works and what works not and what logs you have for working and non working regarding tls and certificates. There is only a subset of information in your question and these are probably no longer accurate too since you've made changes to use the wildcard.

Thanks for the help, Steffen. I found the error and solved it with the help of another thread - I posted the answer here.
I wonder why the PiHole DNS server (FTL) is not able to resolve a duckdns URI? Maybe a CNAME record is needed to redirect "*.foo.duckdns.org" to "duckdns.org"?
